# Angular Checkbox with n-Change - "this"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-change

I have a series of checkboxes:

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-change="??????">
```

I need to set **$scope.mode.someOtherValue = false** if the checkbox is true.

Is there a way to get the value of the checkbox in the **ng-change** so that I can use it to set the value of **$scope.mode.someOtherValue**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In HTML;

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="CheckValue" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-change="valueChanged()">
```

In JS;

```
$scope.valueChanged = function(){
  if($scope.CheckValue == true){
    $scope.mode.someOtherValue = false;
  }else{
    $scope.mode.someOtherValue = true;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps...!